# nginx retry static files once on 404

Tags: nginx

In my test scenario if a file is being created and someone requests the file 404 will be returned. i want to implement a retry once for that file. current configuration

```
location /file/ {
    root /var/www/html/;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @retry;
}
location @retry {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1;
}
```

this works fine for real time file creation and access (if a file returns 404 it retries sort of). but if a file doesn't exists it creates a nested requests (i guess) which will eventually return 503 gateway timeout.
1) is there any better implementation for this ?
2) will nested request also dies when 1st request times out ?

Answer (score 1):

Simply duplicate your location block instead of proxying to localhost.

```
location /file/ {
    root /var/www/html/;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @retry;
}

location @retry {
    root /var/www/html/;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

But considering how fast nginx is to process a request, this retry thing for a static file seems a **really** weird idea. You should fix what you have in mind in your workflow instead.